# Can someone help me express this parametric curve as an implicit curve $f(x,y) = C$?

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, curves, parametric, implicit-function

I have the following parametric equation in polar coordinates:
$$ r(\theta) = r_0 + \Delta r\cos(2\theta),$$ 
where $\Delta r$ is some perturbation to the radius $r_0$. Can anyone help me express the above as an implicit curve $f(x,y)=C$?

Comment: comment clarification can be deleted

Answer (score 0):

$$ \cos \theta =\dfrac{x}{r}$$
$$ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}-r_o =\Delta r\, ( \dfrac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2}-1)$$
$$ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}-r_o =\Delta r \,( \dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2})$$

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! Did not realise it would be that straightforward.